# Complex packaging in gradle for servers with different binaries

Tags: gradle

I have the following dependency structure

```
prodwebserver -> prod.jar -> transitive prod dependencies
devwebserver -> prodwebserver.jar, runtimeCompiler.jar, dev-router.jar -> more transitive dependencies
```

My devwebserver 'will' have ZERO source code.  In gradle, currently I have a target called embeddabledevwebserver which depends on those.

Now I need to package up a release into a format of

```
release
   |
   |--prod - contains all prod jars
   |
   |--development - contains ONLY the extra jars that prod is missing
```

1. How can I get the difference in jar sets between the two targets such that I only put the extra jars needed for development in the development directory?
2. (this is nitpicky and not too important) Is there a way I can do this without having this empty embeddabledevwebserver project which is sort of an annoying shell project?

My actual current build file ...(WIP)...
https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/gradlePackaging/build.gradle

(comments on that file welcome and appreciated)

EDIT: More specifically, I have these sections to start copying/syncing files over

```
task stageTemplate(type: Copy) {
    from '.'
    into buildDir
    include stagingDirName + '/**'
}

task stageWebServer(type: Sync, dependsOn: [':embeddablewebserver:assemble', 'stageTemplate']) {
    from childProjects.embeddablewebserver.toStagingDir
    into new File(outputStagingDir, 'prod')
}

task stageDevServer(type: Sync, dependsOn: [':http-router-dev:assemble', 'stageWebServer']) {
    from childProjects['http-router-dev'].toStagingDir
    into new File(outputStagingDir, 'development')
    exclude stageWebServer
}
```

and I can't exclude stageWebServer from stageDevServer but basically for all the jars that stageWebServer task moved over, I want to filter out all the jars with those same names for the development one.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I finally worked through this adding println to print every object and got to this which works for copy at least...I am not sure if Sync is fully working(ie. if I remove a file from prod and it is still in development, will it show up or not).

```
task stageWebServer(type: Sync, dependsOn: [':embeddablewebserver:assemble', 'stageTemplate']) {
    from childProjects.embeddablewebserver.toStagingDir
    into new File(outputStagingDir, 'prod')
}

task stageDevServer(type: Sync, dependsOn: [':http-router-dev:assemble', 'stageWebServer']) {
    from childProjects['http-router-dev'].toStagingDir
    into new File(outputStagingDir, 'development')
    exclude { details ->
        def fileNames = stageWebServer.source.collect{ entry -> entry.getName()}
        fileNames.contains(details.file.getName())
    }
}
```